# Who is Wolverine promised to?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

In *Uncanny X-Force* issue 12, the team goes to the *Age of Apocalypse* universe, where they meet the alternate-universe-counterparts of the X-Men, including Jean Grey.

Logan muses over his unrequited love for Jean but has an interior monologue about how he is "promised to another woman".

Who is this other woman he is referring to? I've been reading other X-Men titles around the same time period and have not noticed any mention of him being in a relationship.

[image: Wolverine has a promise ring]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since June 2009 till ~2011 (when Uncanny X-Force 12 was released) Logan's girlfriend in Wolverine Vol 4 and Wolverine: Weapon X was [Melita Garner](http://marvel.wikia.com/Melita_Garner_%28Earth-616%29)

[image: Melita Garner]